# EJS / Mongoose - Posts tend to show twice after POST, when I try to GET the same page, it shows up twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Well basically when I POST the create post controller, the post shows up once, the problem is when I GET the same page it shows up twice?

How can I solve this to make so that if the post already exists, then it should not show another time even tho I GET the page?

My goal is that altho the user post or gets the page, it should still be showing once if it exists.

admin controller

```js
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");
const {
    User,
    Post,
} = require("../models/model");

exports.getMyPostsPage = (req, res) => {
    res.render("admin/myposts", {
        path: "/myposts",
        pageTitle: "My Posts",
    })
}

exports.getCreatepostPage = (req, res) => {
    res.render("admin/createpost", {
        path: "/create",
        pageTitle: "Create",
    });
}


exports.getPostsPage = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({})

        res.render("admin/posts", {
            path: "/posts",
            pageTitle: "Posts",
            posts: posts
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }


}

exports.postCreatePost = async (req, res) => {

    const {
        title,
        description,
        context
    } = req.body;

    const post = new Post({
        title,
        description,
        context,
        author: req.user
    });

    try {
        const savedPost = await post.save()
        const usersPost = await req.user.posts.push(post);
        console.log(req.user.posts)
        const posts = await Post.find({})
        res.render("admin/posts", {
            pageTitle: "Posts",
            path: "/posts",
            posts: posts
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

posts.ejs

```html
<%- include("../includes/head.ejs") %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin.css">
</head>

<body>
    <%- include("../includes/navigation.ejs", ) %>
    <% for (const post of posts) { %>
    <div class="posts">
        <form action="/post" method="POST">
            <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
            <p><%=post.description%></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">

            <button type="submit">
                See Post
            </button>


        </form>

    </div>
    <% } %>

    <%- include("../includes/footer.ejs") %>
```

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");




const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    context: String,
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }
});


const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    posts: [postSchema]
});


userSchema.pre("save", async function save(next) {
    const user = this;
    if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    user.password = hashedPassword;
    next();
});


const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = {
    User,
    Post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue when it came to using the f5 button, it repeated the POST part, but it is fine now, it was actually not a real issue just a bug so to speak.